How to find the average power of random and periodic component with given autocorrelation function?
This question is from Communication Systems 5th edition Simon Haykin and Michael Mohel.
A random process $Y(t)$ consists of a dc component $\sqrt{3/2}$ volts, a periodic component $g(t)$ and a random component $X(t)$.  The autocorrelation function of $Y(t)$ is given as:

a) Find average power of periodic component.
b) Find average power of random component.
ONE GUESS is:
a) DC component power: 1.5 units
b) Periodic Component power: 0.5 units
c) Random component power: 1 unit
However, when I properly try to derive it using mathematics, I start with:
$$\mathbb{E}[y(t)y(t+\tau)]=\mathbb{E}[(\sqrt{3/2}+x(t)+g(t))(\sqrt{3/2}+x(t+\tau)+g(t+\tau))]$$
$$\implies 1.5+\sqrt{3/2}\bigg(g(t)+g(t+\tau)+\mathbb{E}[x(t)+x(t+\tau)]\bigg)+g(t)g(t+\tau)+g(t)\mathbb{E}[X(t+\tau)]+g(t+\tau)\mathbb{E}[X(t)]+R_X(\tau)$$
which seems difficult to solve given the parameters in the question and also I am not sure if it is WSS
Where I am wrong?
